# Excel vba: Class sub: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment on vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a class `State` and some sub inside it that takes a `Scripting.Dictionary` as an argument. However when I try to pass a dictionary there, I get a `wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
'Sub insite State class
Sub addSecondItems(itemsDict As Object)
    MsgBox ("start addSecondItems")
End Sub

Sub test()
Dim stateCopy As State
Set stateCopy = New State
...
Dim dict1 As Object
Set dict1 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
stateCopy.addSecondItems (dict1)  'error here
...
End Sub
```

At the same time

```
Sub testPetDict()

    Dim petDict As Object
    Set petDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Call readPetDict(petDict)

End Sub

Sub readPetDict(petDict As Object)
        Dim year As Integer
        For year = 2014 To 2017
            MsgBox (year & ". " & petDict(year))
        Next
End Sub
```

works fine.

What may be wrong here and why the second case works, while the first fails?

Comment: Remove the brackets: `stateCopy.addSecondItems dict1` or use `Call`

Comment: By using parentheses, you force the object to be passed by value, hence the error.

Comment: @Rory Thank you kind person! You saved me from going irreversible desperate! You might post an answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: @Kostas What's wrong with a dictionary being passed by value though? It's not like I need to edit it or something.

Comment: You can't pass an object by value, only by reference. Passing by value means creating and passing a copy where by reference, only a reference to the object is passed.

Comment: You can pass objects by value - that means that a copy of the pointer is passed. The brackets here actually try to evaluate the object and that is what fails (not the property assignment itself) since the default property is `Item` and it requires an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the brackets:

```
stateCopy.addSecondItems dict1
```

or use `Call`

```
Call stateCopy.addSecondItems(dict1)
```

Otherwise the brackets try to coerce the dictionary to a value by calling its default property, `Item`, which requires an argument, hence the error message.